# Reading the frames of a raw video codified in Bayer_rggb8 in python

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I'm trying to read a raw video file codified in bayer_rggb8 in python to store some specific frames. I Know that with FFmpeg I probably store all the frames in the format that I want and then work with them. Still, the point is that this is a first version of the program and the next step is to use it online with a grasshopper camera that sends the data in bayer_rggb8 format, and I want to process the frames without the need of storing them in the disk.
My first try was with the videocapture functions from OpenCV, but it didn't work. I think a right solution may be open the file with `open(filepath,'rb')` and read the number of bytes in a frame, and then transform from rggb8 space to OpenCV bgr. I haven't found a way to do it, however. 
Have you ever done anything similar? Is there a bookstore that can help me? I don't ask for the code directly, but right now I think I'm so lost that I'm not able to see the solutions.

I'm using python 3.6 and opencv in Kubuntu 18.04. The frame size is 600X1920

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution; it was easier than I thought. I think I was blocked

```
video = open(filepath,'rb') 
framesize = 600 * 1920
initbyte = framesize * initframe
video.seek(initbyte)
frame = self.video.read(framesize)
frame = np.frombuffer(frame, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(600,1920)
bgrframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BayerBG2BGR)
```